# Dialog Fragment and Dismissing Touches to Activity's Views

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I have an `activity` and a `dialog` `fragment`. What I do is when `dialog` `fragment` is being shown and user clicks outside dialog fragment, to show an `Alert dialog`.

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return object: Dialog(activity!!, theme) {
        override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE == event.action) {
                presentAlertDialog()
                return true
            }

            return super.onTouchEvent(event)
        }

    }.apply {
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        setCancelable(false)

        window?.apply {
            setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL)
            setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH)
        }
    }
```

If at the point where user `clicked` there is no view at the `activity`, then there is no problem. However, when there is a view (e.g., button ) at the point user clicked, both `alert dialog` and that view's `onClickListener` is called. What I want to do is just to show `alert dialog` and make activity's view to dismiss that touch. Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Edit: To make clearer, I add a screenshot:

[image]

What I want is when user touches outside the dialog fragment (i.e., "Waiting" ) and inside Sign Up button (or any other), I want to show an alert dialog and want Sign Up's onClickListener to dismiss that touch.

Comment: your questions isn't very clear now if you want to close dialog fragment on outside click call setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true). And don't use onTouchEvent

Comment: @Bali added a screenshot - hopefully it is clearer. setCanceledOnTouchOutside isn't working in my case because I want to show an alert dialog when touched outside - not canceling the dialog fragment. What I want to do is prevent Sign Up, Sign In etc. buttons' onClickListeners' getting the touch when user click outside the dialog fragment and on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i guess i understood a little you have two dialogs and when someone clicks outside of first dialog you want to open another. Here is how you can achieve this.

First set `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` then implement **cancel()** listener

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(
    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            //Open another dialog here
        }
    });
```

It's better to use this rather than handling **onTouchEvent** by yourselves. Hope this helps let me know if still has any issues. I might write some code if given time. Cheers!

Comment: Good to hear that